# Access Denied for view and download routes in SonataMediaBundle and Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4, sonata-media-bundle, symfony-routing

I use Symfony 4 (more precise 4.1) with SonataAdminBundle and SonataMediaBundle.

This is my `config/routes/sonata_media.yaml`:

```
sonata_media_gallery:
    resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/gallery.xml'
    prefix: /media/gallery

sonata_media:
    resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/media.xml'
    prefix: /media
```

If I run `php bin/console debug:router` there are the following routes in the output:

```
sonata_media_gallery_index    ANY    ANY    ANY    /media/gallery/
sonata_media_gallery_view     ANY    ANY    ANY    /media/gallery/view/{id}
sonata_media_view             ANY    ANY    ANY    /media/view/{id}/{format}
sonata_media_download         ANY    ANY    ANY    /media/download/{id}/{format}
```

The first two routes work fine, but when I try the other two routes, for example:

```
http://localhost:8000/media/view/
http://localhost:8000/media/view/1/default
http://localhost:8000/media/download/1
http://localhost:8000/media/download/1/default
```

then I always get AccessDeniedException, even though I'm authenticated as `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN`.

The error happens in `vendor/sonata-project/media-bundle/src/Controller/MediaController.php` in `downloadAction` and in `viewAction`. I was digging around in the source code, but can't find the reason for the exception thrown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some research I found the culprit and solved the problem. Here I'd like to share my knowledge.

As I mentioned in the question, the exceptions were thrown from:

```
vendor/sonata-project/media-bundle/src/Controller/MediaController.php
```

in the methods `downloadAction` and `viewAction`. It was the following if-condition:

```
if (!$this->get('sonata.media.pool')->getDownloadSecurity($media)->isGranted($media, $this->getCurrentRequest())) {
    throw new AccessDeniedException();
}
```

which is present in both methods. This led me to `vendor/sonata-project/media-bundle/src/Provider/Pool.php`, and further to `vendor/sonata-project/media-bundle/src/Security/RolesDownloadStrategy.php`. I couldn't find any bug or problem there, but it opened my eyes to another position in my own configuration:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
    - { path: ^/.*, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

How could I be so stupid? The path `/media` is not declared in `security.yml` and can be accessed by not authenticated users. The `SonataMediaBundle` requires per default `ROLE_ADMIN` or `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` for downloading/viewing the media.

The routes for the `Gallery` were accessible because `vendor/sonata-project/media-bundle/src/Controller/GalleryController.php` doesn't check if access is granted.

After finding the culprit the question was which approach to chose to solve the problem

1) Change the route prefix:

```
sonata_media:
    resource: '@SonataMediaBundle/Resources/config/routing/media.xml'
    prefix: /admin/media
```

The declared path in `security.yml` covers now the `media` and `ROLE_ADMIN` and `ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN` can access the routes.

Disadvantage: what if you want to expose the media outside of the admin? And what if other roles should be able to access them.

2) Declare a new path in `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/media/, role: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN] }
```

Now we can expose the media outside of the admin. But the other issue is still there: what if other roles need to access the media?

3) Configure another download strategy in the config for SonataMedia:

```
sonata_media:
    # ...
    contexts:
        default:  # the default context is mandatory
            download:
                strategy: sonata.media.security.connected_strategy
                mode: http
    # ...
```

and adjust the path:

```
access_control:
    # ...
    - { path: ^/media/, role: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED] }
    # ...
```

Now every logged in user can access the media. This solution worked for me.

However it is not a one-size-fits-all recipe. Please check the chapter [security](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/3-x/doc/reference/security.html) from the official documentation to get more detailed information.

Comment: Omg thanks a lot. Had the same issue in my application and didn't find the error because of searching in the wrong files.